# Multiple TransactionScope - fetches outdated information

Tags: wcf, transactionscope

This post is somewhat related to this post of mine:
 [How to synchronize database access in a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166571/how-to-synchronize-database-access-in-a-wcf-service)

The responses I got there were over-complicated and \ or contradicting ... :(

I have created a sample WCF service, and I run 3 instances of clients against it.
The service communicates with an SQL table called names, with several rows.

One client spawns **function 1** in the service.

The second client spawns **function 2** in the service.

**function1** spawns a function on the service that :

a. Changes a specific row from 'Charlie' to 'Chin'

b. waits 5 seconds

c. changes the row again from 'Chin' to 'Carol'

**function2** spawns a function that returns a list of all the names.

It is important to note that both functions in the service are wrapped with 'TransactionScope'.

What I do: I run **function1** (which changes 'Charlie' to 'Chin' and waits for 5 seconds), then immediatly I spawn **function2** which tries to get the list of names but hangs (because **function1** hasn't finished yet), and after couple of seconds **function1** changes the name from 'Chin' to 'Carol' and only then **function2** is released and it returns the list of names.

The things is - the list of names that is returned from **function2** doesn't contain 'Carol' ! it contains 'Charlie' !
Why is this ?
I thought that because **function2** hanged until **function1** finished - it would also fetch the data only when **function1** finished, but apparently this is not the case.

What am I doing wrong ?

I **do not** want to start using locks, because this would slow the whole system down.
I will have approximately 20 methods in my final service, and I don't want all of them to have to use locks...
(only 3-4 methods are for 'reading', but they are the ones that will be used 95% of the time)...

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to lock the data that is being changed such that the other process cannot read the data until the first process is complete.

You use the TransactionScope to do this. Set the isolation level to serializable. This will lock the data. You may have to specify that the read also updates the data (to the same values) to get the second call to wait.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: In the link you supplied it says 'By default, the System.Transactions infrastructure creates Serializable transactions.'. This means that 'The highest isolation level, Serializable, provides a high degree of protection against interruptive transactions, but requires that each transaction complete before any other transactions are allowed to operate on the data.' But this is not the behavior I saw. Indeed - 'Function 2' halted and waited till 'Function 1' finished, but the data it actually read was the data that was before 'Function 1's changes ! it should have shown a fresh set of data !

Comment: UPDATE : I now see that I forgot to do 'transaction.Complete();'. Stupid me ... :)
I now see that it is enough to only wrap 'Function 1' with a transaction scope, and this makes 'Function 2' get the right information (it waits till function 1 finishes) even though 'Function 2' doesn't have a transaction scope !
this is great ! 
Can you tell me why this is ?
and what happens if I have called 'Function 2' from 2 different clients ? which one will fire first when 'Function 1' finishes ? first-come-first-served ?