# Resolving MemberChangeConflict with a specific value

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a counter in SQL that needs to go down each time a user does an activity. At times the activity is fast and furious and I end up with a ChangeConflictException. This is fine, but when it happens I would like the final value to be the combination of both changes.

Something like this

```
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (ChangeConflictException cce)
{
    foreach (ObjectChangeConflict occ in db.ChangeConflicts)
    {
        foreach (MemberChangeConflict mcc in occ.MemberConflicts)
        {
            if (mcc.DatabaseValue is int)
            {
                mcc.FinalValue = mcc.DatabaseValue + mcc.CurrentValue - mcc.OriginalValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample values, original value is 50, current value is 30 (less 20) and database value is 40 (less 10 from original). The final value should be 40-20 = 20.

Except of course, there is no such thing as mcc.FinalValue. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`MemberChangeConflict.Resolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300130.aspx) method.

```
mcc.Resolve(mcc.DatabaseValue + mcc.CurrentValue - mcc.OriginalValue);
```

(And don't forget to call `SubmitChanges` again after you loop through your conflicts.)

Comment: Hmm, if I call SubmitChanges again, the error might happen again, no?

Comment: You can always surround your try/catch statements with a loop that's broken out of upon a successful submission.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd say be careful about adding lots of code to a catch block. It's usually better to queue up code needing to be executed after an exception.

The solution to your problem would be to use a transaction to first read the data and then submit changes.

See this stack overflow question for an example of transactions.

[How to create a LINQ to SQL Transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755796/how-to-create-a-linq-to-sql-transaction)

Comment: Looks like Linq to SQL is already wrapped in a transaction scope (at the bottom), though I'm not sure how that is if I have to pull data to check that it is not null.